# What is the difference between link_to and link_to_unless_current?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm ust a beginner using Ruby on Rails for building website.. Here they have not clearly mentioned the difference between `link_to` and `link_to_unless_current`.

Answer (score 2):

`link_to` will always generate a link.

`link_to_unless_current` will be ignored if the URL it would link to is the same as the URL that rendered the view containing it.

Answer (score 1):

`link_to` just generates a link, `link_to_unless_current` only creates the link if the current page is not equal to the link you provided.

There is also a `link_to_unless` method, where you can provide a custom condition when to show the link.

For more information take a look at [the UrlHelper documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html).

Answer (score 0):

Link_to refers to "redirecting no matter what", and link_to_unless_current redirects unless it is already the current page.